# Java best practice - Object instantiation vs Object reference to null

Tags: java

Please help me to understand the below scenario.
I have a user PoJO and it contains properties userId, userName, userEmail and associated setter and getter methods.
I'm writing a method as per below.

```
public User getUser(someReference){
 User usr = new User();
 usr = someInterface.getUser(someReferenceId);
.....
....
 return usr;
}

public User getUser(someReference){
 User usr = null;
 usr = someInterface.getUser(someReferenceId);
.....
....
return usr;

}
```

Please help me to understand from the above two methods w.r.to User instantiation.

Comment: In the first one you are creating a useless object. The second one is better, but could be simplified just to `User usr = someInterface.getUser(someReferenceId);`. Remember - every call of the `new` operator **creates** an object

Comment: The first creates an instance of User to initialize variable `usr` with, then throws it away to re-assign `usr` to the reference returned from `someInterface.getUser()`.  This seems like a bad idea.  The second initializes `usr` to null, then reassigns it... A better idea.  But why not just initialize `usr` to the reference returned by the call to  `someInterface.getUser()` ?

Comment: Why not just `User usr = someInterface.getUser(someReferenceId);`? The first one causes unnecessary heap usage, that is immediately garbage collected. The second doesn't need the explicit assignment to null, thats what it is by default.

Comment: *Java best practice:* Neither. Don't declare variable until needed *(see [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585259/java-best-practice-object-instantiation-vs-object-reference-to-null#comment90136060_51585259) above)*, or if you insist on two lines, simply don't initialize it on the first line.

Comment: @PaulRooney actually it not specified when that object will be garbage collected (rarely it will happen as soon as object's reference count goes to zero). Also - in methods, references and variables are not default initialized. Delcaring `User usr;` will **not** yield true for `usr == null`. It will result in a compilation error

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. Now I understand the difference between those two and the better way to handle such scenario. In this scenario, I can initialize usr to the reference returned by the interface.getUser().

Comment: yes I should have worded my comment more clearly "is available for garbage collection".

Comment: @Fureeish: No production JVM uses reference counts, so that's not relevant here. And more importantly, a modern JIT will likely elide (or hoist to the stack) the entire object allocation in this case, as even simple escape analysis can prove that the object is never referenced once its constructor completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the code in the question, the first version pointlessly creates a User object, which is then dereferenced (thrown away) in the next line.

The second version creates no instances (assigning `null` does nothing but “clear” the variable, although the code behind `someInterface.getUser()` may create an instance).

I would simplify your code to:

```
User usr = someInterface.getUser(someReferenceId);
```